# rxjs insert delayed data

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Into a rxjs-Stream i want to conditionaly insert data, a delay and then the original event.

```
from(Array(10).keys())
  .pipe(
    map(i => ({ data: i })),
    concatMap(e => {
      if (e.data === 3) {
        return of(e)
          .pipe(
            delay(500),
          );
      }
      return of(e);
    }),
  )
  .subscribe(i => console.log(i));
```

This creates a delay before `{ data: 3 }`.

But i want to emit `{ data: 'a' }`, delay, `{ data: 3 }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `merge` method to achieve what you want :

```
 concatMap((e) => {
      if (e.data === 3) {
        return merge(of({ data: 'a' }), of(e).pipe(delay(500)));
      }
      return of(e);
    })
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-a7yssc?file=index.ts)